# Sql trigger not not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi I've a student table where I have columns like username, usertype, password etc.
I have wrote a trigger for the this table which creates a username for the for the usertype 'Student', Here is the trigger codes

```
> DROP TRIGGER `sasis`.`USERNAMEAutoGen`;

DELIMITER ||

CREATE TRIGGER `sasis`.`USERNAMEAutoGen` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `sasis`.`userinfo` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    if (usertype== 'Student')
      declare i varchar(2);
      declare usrnm varchar(20);
      declare fullusrnm varchar(255);
      declare curyr varchar(10);
      declare curm varchar(10);
      declare rcount varchar(50);
      set i='I';
      select date_format(now(),'%y') into curyr;
      select date_format(now(),'%b') into curm;
      set usrnm=concat(i,curyr,upper(curm));
      select count(*) into rcount from userinfo where username like concat(usrnm,'%');
      if(rcount<9) then
        set rcount=concat('0000',(rcount+1));
      elseif (rcount<99) then
        set rcount=concat('000',(rcount+1));
      elseif (rcount<999) then
        set rcount=concat('00',(rcount+1));
      end  if;
      set fullusrnm=concat(i,curyr,upper(curm),rcount);
       if (new.username is null or trim(new.username)='') then
        set NEW.username=fullusrnm;
      end if;   end if; END||

DELIMITER ;
```

It was working before, but now its showing some error which states that there is a syntax error near '=='Student') declare i varchar(2). etc. And I have no clue how to solve it
please help with your valuable answers. Thanks in advance.

I have tried with "if (usertype= 'Student') THEN" as well but then it shows error message like syntax error near declare i varchar(2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I browsed on the manual, I can't see any `==` supported,

- [MySQL OPERATORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html)

So in your `TRIGGER`, should only be `IF (usertype = 'Student') THEN`

FULL TRIGGER CODE

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sasis`.`USERNAMEAutoGen` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `sasis`.`userinfo` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  

    declare i varchar(2);
    declare usrnm varchar(20);
    declare fullusrnm varchar(255);
    declare curyr varchar(10);
    declare curm varchar(10);
    declare rcount varchar(50);

    IF (usertype== 'Student') THEN

        set i='I';
        select date_format(now(),'%y') into curyr;
        select date_format(now(),'%b') into curm;
        set usrnm=concat(i,curyr,upper(curm));
        select count(*) into rcount from userinfo where username like concat(usrnm,'%');

        if(rcount<9) then
            set rcount=concat('0000',(rcount+1));
        elseif (rcount<99) then
            set rcount=concat('000',(rcount+1));
        elseif (rcount<999) then
            set rcount=concat('00',(rcount+1));
        end  if;

        set fullusrnm=concat(i,curyr,upper(curm),rcount);
        if (new.username is null or trim(new.username)='') then
            set NEW.username=fullusrnm;
        end if; 

      end if; 
END||

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried it before then it show syntax error near declare i varchar(2);

Comment: I updated the answer. Declaration must be on the first part of the statement and you have you `THEN` keyword on the first `IF` statement.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure mysql allows == as equality operator?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran I was merely politely telling him that there is no such thing as == in mysql. Hopefully he didn't miss my point